# Updating with modifier operators in the Mongo CLI works but not from node.js code using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Connecting to our Mongo instance using the CLI, you can use the update modifier operators just fine:

> db.users.update({nickname: 'mcoalson'}, { "$addToSet" : { room_ref : "b"}})
>   db.users.update({nickname: 'mcoalson'}, { "$addToSet" : { room_ref : "c"}})
>   db.users.findOne({nickname: 'mcoalson'})
>   {
>       "_id" : ObjectId("4de5e9e982e9556c2a000003"),
>       "nickname" : "mcoalson",
>       "room_ref" : [
>           "a",
>           "d",
>           "b",
>           "c"
>       ]
>   }

However doing the exact same thing in the node.js on the same document there are no results.

```
db.User.update({'nickname': 'mcoalson'}, {"$pullAll": {'room_ref': ["b"]}});
db.User.update({'nickname': 'mcoalson'}, {"$addToSet": {'room_ref': "f"}});
```

"room_ref" : [
        "a",
        "d",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]

Clearly "b" was not removed and "f" was not added.  I have tried every conceivable quotation scenario I could think of yet nothing ever changes.  I can use the find() and findOne() from node.js code and am using the same credentials, any advice?

Comment: Are you dead certain that there is only 1 document in the db with nickname 'mcoalson'?  If not, you need to pass the 'multiple' option to update more than one document at a time.

Comment: Please make sure that your mongoose version is up-to-date. There were a lot of bugfixes for `update` lately: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/commits/master

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.

The mongo CLI is synchronous, node.js is async. Are you using the code as you posted, or do you have proper callbacks? Your test should look like this:

```
db.User.update({'nickname': 'mcoalson'}, {"$pullAll": {'room_ref': ["b"]}}, function(){
    db.User.findOne({'nickname': 'mcoalson'}, function(user){
        console.log('changed user:', user)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and ended up bypassing mongoose and using the underlying driver, in which the problem didn't occur.

So instead of

```
db.User.update(...)
```

Use:

```
db.User.collection.update(...)
```

Hope that helps.